# How to ping instance's internal network from Host on Devstack

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am running Devstack on my machine and i would like to know if it is possible to ping an instance from Host. The default external network of Devstack is 172.24.4.0/24 and br-ex on Host has the IP 172.24.4.1. I launch an instance using the internal network of Devstack (192.168.233.0/24) and the instance gets the IP 192.168.233.100. My Host's IP is 192.168.1.10. Is there a way to ping 192.168.233.100 from my Host? Another thing i thought is to boot up a VM directly to the external network (172.24.4.0/24) but the VM does not boot up correctly. I can only use that network for associating floating IP's.

I have edited the security group and i have allowed ICMP and SSH, so this is not a problem.

Comment: Correct me if I misunderstand your question, you have tried to associate a floating IP (172.24.4.x) to the instance which has an internal IP `192.168.233.100`, but what you really want to do is `ping 192.168.233.100` directly from outside (which has IP 192.168.1.10)?

Comment: That is exactly what i want to do, but i think it is not possible. Right?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.